# OpenJDK keytool password

Tags: java, keytool, jsse

I am trying to register a corporate certificate for https connection in OpenJDK

I ran the following command in `OpenJDK` verion 8. It asked me to enter in the password. The default password for Oracle JDK is "changeit", but it doesn't work with OpenJDK

I have tried to use the password `changeit` but it didn't work.

OpenJDK 8:

```
D:\java8\bin\keytool.exe -keystore "D:\java8\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -importcert -alias sds -file C:\Users\SDS\SDS.crt
```

OpenJDK version 11:

```
D:\jdk-11.0.2\lib\security>D:\jdk-11.0.2\bin\keytool.exe -keystore D:\jdk-11.0.2\lib\security\cacerts -importcert -alias sds -file C:\Users\SDS\SDS.crt
```

OpenJDK 8 :

```
keytool 오류: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

OpenJDK version 11, the same problem occurs:

```
Warning: use -cacerts option to access cacerts keystore
Enter keystore password:
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was
```

Comment: Someone probably has taken `changeit` to heart and changed it. You might be able to find the password in the configuration/properties file of any installed Java supporting web server.

Comment: You will *certainly* find it in the documentation. Look harder.

Answer (score 8):

For OpenJDK 8, first double check the password:

```
cd D:\java8\jre\lib\security
keytool -list -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit
```

If it continues to give you the same error, find the exact version of your Java 8 installation and download the corresponding ZIP archive from [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html#x64_win) (e.g. [OpenJDK8U-jre_x64_windows_hotspot_8u212b04.zip](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u212-b04/OpenJDK8U-jre_x64_windows_hotspot_8u212b04.zip)).

Extract the `cacerts` file (`lib/security/cacerts`) and using a binary diff tool (e.g. [fc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fc)) compare the contents of the `cacerts` file from the downloaded archive to your local version. If they are not identical, it is possible that your `D:\java8\jre\lib\security\cacerts` file has been modified.

You can follow a similar procedure for validating the OpenJDK 11's `cacerts` file.

Also: you don't need to import the custom certificates into the the original `D:\java8\jre\lib\security\cacerts` file. I personally rarely do that. Instead, keep the original but create a copy of it in a custom folder and add your corporate certificates to that. In your case, you can copy the `cacerts` file from the ZIP file and move it to your home directory and add your corporate certificates to that, as you don't know the password for `D:\java8\jre\lib\security\cacerts`.

Then when you run a Java program, configure it to use your custom `cacerts` file instead of the default `cacerts` file:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path/to/custom/cacerts
     -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
     ...
```

One more thing: ask your administrator -- maybe he has deliberately changed the password for the `cacerts` file.

Answer (score -1):

I used AdoptOpenJDK but it gave me the same results. It's run on Windows 10 cmd with administrative privilege.

```
C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.3.7-hotspot\bin\keytool"  -keystore  "C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.3.7-hotspot\lib\security\cacerts"  -importcert -alias sds -file C:\Users\SDS\SDS.crt
경고: -cacerts 옵션을 사용하여 cacerts 키 저장소에 액세스하십시오.
키 저장소 비밀번호 입력:
keytool 오류: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

I executed the following command and it says the key storage file exists (in Korean language).

```
C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.3.7-hotspot\bin>.\keytool -list -keystore "C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.3.7-hotspot\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit
경고: -cacerts 옵션을 사용하여 cacerts 키 저장소에 액세스하십시오.
키 저장소 유형: JKS
키 저장소 제공자: SUN

키 저장소에 93개의 항목이 포함되어 있습니다.

verisignclass2g2ca [jdk], 2018. 6. 13., trustedCertEntry,
인증서 지문(SHA-256): 3A:43:E2:20:FE:7F:3E:A9:65:3D:1E:21:74:2E:AC:2B:75:C2:0F:D8:98:03:05:BC:50:2C:AF:8C:2D:9B:41:A1
digicertassuredidg3 [jdk], 2017. 12. 1., trustedCertEntry,
인증서 지문(SHA-256): 7E:37:CB:8B:4C:47:09:0C:AB:36:55:1B:A6:F4:5D:B8:40:68:0F:BA:16:6A:95:2D:B1:00:71:7F:43:05:3F:C2
verisignuniversalrootca [jdk], 2017. 12. 1., trustedCertEntry,
인증서 지문(SHA-256): 23:99:56:11:27:A5:71:25:DE:8C:EF:EA:61:0D:DF:2F:A0:78:B5:C8:06:7F:4E:82:82:90:BF:B8:60:E8:4B:3C
```

Comment: I don't think this an answer to your question, is it? If not and it is additional information to your question, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56847306/edit) your question and include this information rather than posting it as an answer. If you do so, please delete this answer.